# argparse: Converter Function for Option with Multiple Parameters?

Tags: lua, command-line-arguments, argparse

I would like to apply different conversion function to the parameters of an option.

Consider this following code:

```
parser:option('-c --circle')
   :argname{'<radius>', '<coordinates>'}
   -- does not work like this:
   -- :convert{['<radius>']=tonumber, ['<coordinates>']=tocoords}
   :default{1, {0,0}}
   :args(2)
   :count '0-1'
```

As you can see the program has an option `-c` which takes two parameters: `radius` and `coordinates`. I would like to apply to different conversion functions (`tonumber` and `tocoords`) respectively. Reading [the documentation](https://argparse.readthedocs.io/en/0.5.0/callbacks.html?highlight=malformed) I can't figure out how to do this.

Is this possible and if so then what is the correct way to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are correct that the Lua Argparse system does not allow you to specify multiple functions to convert the arguments to a specific option, then there may still be a way to do it. After all, Argparse has to call your conversion function once for each argument. And there's no rule that the conversion function has to do the same thing for each invocation. The only information you don't have is the particular argument it is being called on.

So... *cheat*. Create that information, by using Lua's first-class functions (note: the following uses Lua 5.3):

```
local function multi_arg_parser(...)
  local index = 0
  local funcs = table.pack(...)
  return function(...)
    index = index + 1
    return funcs[index](...)
  end
end

parser:option('-c --circle')
   :argname{'<radius>', '<coordinates>'}
   :convert(multi_arg_parser(tonumber, tocoords))
   :default{1, {0,0}}
   :args(2)
   :count '0-1'
```

This will work *provided* that Argparse will call the `convert` function exactly once for each argument *and* call `convert` on the arguments in the order they appear in the command line. That is almost certainly not guaranteed by Argparse, but it's a reasonable assumption.

Answer (score 2):

Since argparse 0.6.0 this works:

```
:convert{tonumber, tocoords}
```

See [documentation](https://argparse.readthedocs.io/en/0.6.0/callbacks.html):

> If convert property of an element is an array of functions, they will be used as converters for corresponding arguments in case the element accepts multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the **[Lapp Framework](https://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.lapp.html)**. It **supports conversions** via a converter method passed to the [add_type](https://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/libraries/pl.lapp.html#add_type) method. Also, it comes with other convenient features, like assertions and default values.